AWS spot datafeed subscription not populating bucket
I have a spot datafeed subscription set up, the command to set it up ran successfully, and when I run aws ec2 describe-spot-datafeed-subscription I get the below (Bucket and OwnerID changed):
{
    "SpotDatafeedSubscription": {
        "Bucket": "my-bucket",
        "OwnerId": "000000000000",
        "Prefix": "datafeed",
        "State": "Active"
    }
}

However, I've had this set up for about a month, and nothing has ever appeared in the bucket. Ownership is Bucket owner preferred and the ACL has the AWS external account added to it as the docs say, but the bucket remains empty.

Did you follow the KMS advice from this page? Fix an Amazon S3-configured data feed for EC2 Spot Instances | AWS re:Post

@JohnRotenstein I'm not using a customer managed key, just the default one to remove as many variables as possible.

Are you sure that you are running a Spot Instance in the same region? The documentation says: "If you don't have a Spot Instance running during a certain hour, you don't receive a data feed file for that hour."

@JohnRotenstein Without a doubt. It's where the kubernetes cluster lives as well a a couple of other workloads that use spots, we've got at a minimum 10 spots running at any one time.

Confirmed by running aws ec2 describe-spot-instance-requests and getting list of instances with active status.

I figured it out. The docs aren't entirely clear. Turns out you need to add the key permissions to a customer managed key if you have encryption at all. And because not having encryption is no longer an option, you have to use a customer managed key, not the default one!
